# Problems with Curl in Discord Oauth2

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0, discord

the problem is simple.

when the oAuth2 code is sent to the page. This php script to receive the token json not work. Please, help me :c

```
$base64 = base64_encode($data['id'] . ':' . $data['secret']);

$info = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($info, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=" . $data['code'] . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($data['redirect']),
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: Basic " . $base64,                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($base64)
    ),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
));

$tinyresult = curl_exec($info);
curl_close($info);

return $tinyresult;
```

Comment: _How_ does it "not work"? What response do you get? What is the value of `$tinyresult`?

Comment: the result is nothing. the response only waits several seconds to receive an empty page

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($tinyresult)`? Is this in a function since I note you're using `return` and don't do anything with the response otherwise in the snippet.

Comment: this is a function. the var_dump($tinyresult) returned a value false

Comment: What does [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) tell you?

Comment: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved :D

```
    $info = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($info, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token",
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
            "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
            "client_id" => $data['id'],
            "client_secret" => $data['secret'],
            "redirect_uri" => $data['redirect'],
            "code" => $data["code"],
        ),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    ));

    $tinyresult = curl_exec($info);
    if ($tinyresult == false) {
        $tinyerror = curl_error($info);
    } else {
        $tinyerror = null;
        $tinyresult = json_decode($tinyresult);
    }

    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($info, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_close($info);

    return array(
        "data" => $tinyresult,
        "err" => $tinyerror,
        "state" => $httpcode,
    );
```